# Python Flask catch multiple Integrity errors = different error messages if user or email throws integrity error

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a simple registration function, where a new user has to give following informations:

**Email (is unique)**

**Username (is unique, primary key)**

**Password**

**Confirm Password**

Problem:

If the user fills in all informations and username or email are already in database, I get an integrity error, which is okay. I can try catch it and display an information that one of those is already used.

But it would be much more usefull if I could tell exactly what is already used. For example the email could be okay but if the username is used, it should tell "Choose an other username".

Hope you got the Problem.

Thats the code I use (there is also already a verification functionality in it but it works fine and is not important):

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
form = NewUserForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    new_user = User(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password=make_hash(form.password.data))
    try:
        if new_user:
            db_session.add(new_user)
            db_session.commit()
            token = generate_confirmation_token(new_user.email)

            confirm_url = url_for('confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)

            html = render_template('activate.html', confirm_url=confirm_url)

            subject = "Bitte bestätigen Sie Ihre Registrierung"

            send_email(new_user.email, subject, html)

            login_user(new_user)
            flash('Registrierung erfolgreich! Wir haben Ihnen einen Bestätigungsemail auf die, von Ihnen angegebene Adresse zugeschickt. Bestätigen Sie bitte Ihre Registrierung.')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        else:
            flash('Neuer Nutzer konnte nicht angelegt werden!')
    except IntegrityError:
        flash('Nutzer oder Email ist bereits vergeben, anderer Nutzername erforderlich')
return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

What I need is a way to specify wether user or email throwed the integrity error and to display the apropriate message.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to change to `except IntegrityError as e` and inspect the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using wtf form then you can override the validate method of NewUserForm

```
class NewUserForm(Form):
    username = TextField('Username', [validators.Required()])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None

    def validate(self):
        rv = Form.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        user = User.query.filter_by(
            username=self.username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            self.username.errors.append(' username taken ')
            return False

        self.user = user
        return True
```

while in template you can render the errors as following:

```
{% for field in form.errors %}
{% for error in form.errors[field] %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <strong>Error!</strong> {{error}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would lead to race conditions.